# mongodb variables $match

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

Estoy intentando recoger de una colección todos los contactos excepto aquellos que su número de teléfono se encuentra en la blacklist. Tengo el siguiente pipeline pero no sé como reformatearlo para que en vez del número de teléfono hard-codeado, se utilice el campo mobile_phone que está en la colección "contactos".

```
db.getCollection("contactos").aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "blacklist",
            "localField": "mobile_phone",
            "foreignField": "phone",
            "as": "Blacklist"
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "Blacklist.phone": {
                "$ne": "+34000000000"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Y la variable `$mobile_phone` de qué tipo es y dónde la declaras?

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Acabo de reformular la última frase para que se entienda mejor. Lo que quiero averiguar es que debo modificar en el pipeline para que en vez de usar el número +34000000000, se recoja el valor del campo mobile_phone que está en la colección de contactos.

Comment: La etapa `$lookup` está buscando en la colección `blacklist` un documento cuyo campo `phone` sea igual al campo `mobile_phone` de la colección `contactos`. Para qué quieres hacer `$match` si ya lo haces con el `$lookup`? Si en la colección de `blacklist` existe un documento tal que `phone == mobile_phone`, pues el campo `Blacklist` que estás creando contendrá dicho documento de `blacklist`. Tal vez la etapa `$match` que buscas es: `$match: { 'Blacklist': {$size: 0 } }`, que significa que te quedarás con aquellos documentos que no tengan correspondencia en la colección `blacklist`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Ahora si funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea filtrar documentos de una colección llamada `contactos`, para obtener todos los documentos cuyo campo `mobile_phone` no se encuentre en la lista negra, esta última representada por documentos de la colección `blacklist` que contienen un campo llamado `phone`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una posible solución es usar una etapa de agregación de tipo [`$lookup`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) que nos permitirá obtener los documentos de la colección `blacklist` cuyo campo `phone` coincida con el campo `mobile_phone` de la colección de `contactos`. Por ejemplo:

```js
db.getCollection('contactos').aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'blacklist',
      localField: 'mobile_phone',
      foreignField: 'phone',
      as: 'blacklist'
    }
  }
])
```

Luego, para quedarnos sólo con aquellos documentos que no tengan coincidencia en la colección de `blacklist` usaremos una etapa [`$match`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) como la siguiente:

```js
{
  $match: {
    'blacklist': { $size: 0 }
  }
}
```

En esta etapa hemos filtrado los documentos que no tengan ninguna correspondencia con `blacklist` inspeccionando el tamaño del Array creado por la etapa `$lookup` anterior.

Sin embargo, este método no es tan eficiente como tener la lista de teléfonos previamente.

Por ejemplo, podríamos hacer lo siguiente:

```js
const blacklist = db.getCollection('blacklist').find().toArray().map(b => b.phone);
```

Luego ya podríamos obtener los contactos que no están en dicha lista usando una simple consulta `find` sobre dicha colección así:

```js
db.getCollection('contactos').find({
  mobile_phone: { $nin: blacklist }
});
```

Hemos usado el operador de consulta [`$nin`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/).

Siempre que puedas evitar un proceso de agregación, evítalo, ya que es más costoso en recursos que la consulta de tipo`find`.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.